# C# Regex to match the keyword in TEXT and get few words around the match

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match the text and get words around the match.

For example my text is in HTML format and i will use below as a sample

```
<p>Do not forget the error handling, I don't exactly know what happens if it wants to replace an occurence and can't find it</p>
<p>Edit: If you have multiple entries which should be replaced, loop the replace part until it will not be able to replace anymore then it will throw an error you can catch to continue</p>
```

MATCH CASE:

Case 1(if match word in in between): `occurence`

RESULT : `I don't exactly know what happens if it wants to replace an occurence and can't find it`

Case 2(if match word in first word): `Do not`

RESULT : `Do not forget the error handling, I don't exactly know what happens if it wants to replace an occurence and can't find it`

Case 3(if match word in last word in the text): `to continue`

RESULT : `If you have multiple entries which should be replaced, loop the replace part until it will not be able to replace anymore then it will throw an error you can catch to continue`

If it is word in between text the it should get text around the word.
If match word is first word then it should get the text from the first word itself

If match is last word the it from get the text before the matched last word.

REGEX `(?<=(\w+)\s)?(continue)(?=\s(\w+))?`

It match's the word only how can i get let us say 10 -15 words around the matched keyword.

Is this possible using Regex

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please reconsider the text cases. How is that possible that in one test case you need exactly 12 repetitions in front of the keyword, and in the other you need much more than 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1:

```
([\w\s']+(?:occurence)[^<]+)|>((?:occurence)[^<]+)|[^>]+(?:occurence)<
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY4gE8/1)

Output:

> I don't exactly know what happens if it wants to replace an occurence
>   and can't find it

Case 2:

```
([\w\s']+(?:Do not)[^<]+)|>((?:Do not)[^<]+)|[^>]+(?:Do not)<
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/hX8cD1/1)

Output:

> Do not forget the error handling, I don't exactly know what happens if
>   it wants to replace an occurence and can't find it

Case 3:

```
([\w\s']+(?:to continue)[^<]+)|>((?:to continue)[^<]+)|[^>]+(?:to continue)<
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD8mV9/1)

Output:

> Edit: If you have multiple entries which should be replaced, loop the
>   replace part until it will not be able to replace anymore then it will
>   throw an error you can catch to continue

**Limit words:**

Case 1:

```
>(Do not(?:\s(?:[\w']+),?){0,100})|((?:\s(?:[\w']+)){0,100}\s?Do not(?:\s(?:[\w']+),?){0,100})|((?:\s(?:[\w',]+)){0,100}\s?Do not)<
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE1mX9/1)

Case 2:

```
>(occurence(?:\s(?:[\w']+),?){0,100})|((?:\s(?:[\w']+)){0,100}\s?occurence(?:\s(?:[\w']+),?){0,100})|((?:\s(?:[\w',]+)){0,100}\s?occurence)<
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG2hH1/1)

Case 3:

```
>(continue(?:\s(?:[\w']+),?){0,100})|((?:\s(?:[\w']+)){0,100}\s?continue(?:\s(?:[\w']+),?){0,100})|((?:\s(?:[\w',]+)){0,100}\s?continue)<
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA9bG1/1)

Comment: One more question, Where have you specified number of words to retrieve as i cant see it in the above regex..

Comment: Edited: Number of word here `{0,100}`